# Send Email form - jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, email

I have bought a template and in the contact page, there is a form but I do not have any idea, how do I forward the messages, which are sent using this form to my mail account.

The code looks so,

```
<div class="alignleft span3 form_content_contact">
                              <h5>Send me a message </h5>
                                <form>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name">
                                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email">
                                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="input-block-level" placeholder="This is a Subject">
                                        <textarea rows="3" id="description" name="description" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                                        <button type="submit" class="last_button btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sample btn-large">Send Email</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sample btn-large">Clean</button>

                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Comment: jQuery can't send emails, you'll need a webserver set up with a mail  client to do that.

Comment: you need server-side programmation or using the user's mail client usign a mailto: link, but you need him to send it.

Comment: As I said, I have bought this template and must modify it according to my information. Possibly there is a webserver set up but do not know where to modify.

Comment: You need to change `<form>` to  `<form action="myserver/someemailprocess.php">` for example - ask your ISP what myserver/someemailprocess.php could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting provider should have a sample code to send an email. Just find it and make the form to send data to it. This is a complete server side work(except sending the data to server) and has nothing to do with javascript or jquery